# Ornament as an entry in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, pgfornament

I have a book containing a number of chapters and several indices.  I would like to place an ornament in the TOC between the list of chapters and the list of indices.  My simple approach fails (see below, comment out the first example and uncomment the second one).

Is there some way to protect the \pgfornament statement so that this will work?

Note: You'll need an xindy style file to get the index to show up when compiling.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex 
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[letterpaper,titlepage,twoside,openany,12pt]{book}

%Use Junicode for a nice looking font
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Junicode}[Language=Icelandic,Fractions=On]

\usepackage[xindy,splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Index of Tale Information,program=texindy,intoc,columns=2,options=-L icelandic -C utf8 -M lang/icelandic/utf8 -M generalstyle]

\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter[Mori]{Móri}
        \index{icelandic!Mori the Hound}
        \index{icelandic titles!Hundurinn Móri}
        \index{collectors!Árnason, Jón}

        \Large Main text

        This is the ornament that I would like in the TOC before the index.

        \pgfornament[width=8cm]{88}

        %Try to add the ornament to the TOC before the index entry
        %It works with simple text
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}%
            {\hfill This should be an ornament \hfill}{}}
        %It fails with a tikz object
        %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\pgfornament[width=8cm]{88}}{}}

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you try adding `\protect` before `\pgfornament`?

Comment: `\addtocontents{toc}{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\pgfornament[width=8cm]{88}}` works, but this is left aligned. Probably you want it centered.

Comment: I feel stupid - I could have sworn I tried that.  You're right it does work.  \hfill on each side centers it.

Comment: Hmm... it works with my minimal example, but not in my book.  I think hyperref has modified a macro; looking into that now.

Answer (score 3):

This puts the ornament in a `\parbox` of length `\textwidth` and centers it with `\centering`. You have to `\protect` both `\centering` and `\pgfornament`:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\nobreak\smallskip\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering\protect\pgfornament[width=8cm]{88}}}
```

This is the result.

[image]

This is the MWE.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex 
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[letterpaper,titlepage,twoside,openany,12pt]{book}

%Use Junicode for a nice looking font
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
%\setmainfont{Junicode}[Language=Icelandic,Fractions=On]

%\usepackage[xindy,splitindex]{imakeidx}
%\makeindex[title=Index of Tale Information,program=texindy,intoc,columns=2,options=-L icelandic -C utf8 -M lang/icelandic/utf8 -M generalstyle]

\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter[Mori]{Móri}
%        \index{icelandic!Mori the Hound}
%        \index{icelandic titles!Hundurinn Móri}
%        \index{collectors!Árnason, Jón}

        \addtocontents{toc}{\nobreak\smallskip\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering\protect\pgfornament[width=8cm]{88}}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The reason my original attempt at using \addtocontents using \protect failed in my original document, but worked in my MWE was due to my use of the hyperref package, which redefines \contentsline.

The following *does* work:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex 
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[letterpaper,titlepage,twoside,openany,12pt]{book}

%Use Junicode for a nice looking font
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Junicode}[Language=Icelandic,Fractions=On]

\usepackage[xindy,splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Index of Tale Information,program=texindy,intoc,columns=2,options=-L icelandic -C utf8 -M lang/icelandic/utf8 -M generalstyle]

\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

%Provide hyperlinks in the T.O.C. to the chapters
%Note: should be last package loaded
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter[Mori]{Móri}
        \index{icelandic!Mori the Hound}
        \index{icelandic titles!Hundurinn Móri}
        \index{collectors!Árnason, Jón}

        \Large Main text

        This is the ornament that I would like in the TOC before the index.

        \pgfornament[width=8cm]{88}

        %Try to add the ornament to the TOC before the index entry
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\hfill%
                \protect\pgfornament[width=8cm]{88}%
                \hfill}{\protect\relax}{}}

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: no, `hyperref` does not redefine `\addtocontents`. It redefines `\contentsline` (and `\addcontentsline`).

Comment: Fixed description to reflect that.

Comment: ok, but from looking at your mwe in the question, I see `\contentsline`. It is the latter which causes problem if you put it directlty in the toc using `\addtocontents`. Because `\addtocontents` isn't modified by `hyperref`, but `\contentsline` is. So it is missing one argument.

Comment: if you used `\addcontentsline` (which is modified by hyperref), and not `\addtocontents` (which isn't) you would have no problem.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup, I've corrected the description above.

Comment: I initially tried \addcontentsline in my original book and it didn't work.  Something about \addcontentsline being a delayed write and not working properly when on the same level as a bunch of include statements (each chapter is added using \include before I get to the \printindex).  After fighting with trying to use direct write statements I went back to \addtocontents.  (In other words, I clearly don't understand all the delayed write and .aux files stuff very well...)

Comment: oh yes I also have had troubles with delayed writes and I sympathize much with you ;-) ... but `\addcontentsline` is a one-line wrapper of `\addtocontents` and the delayed write is initiated by the latter... anyway, the good point is that you solved your problem!